# QGIS OTB Machine Learning algorithms do not create output

Tags: qgis, orfeo-toolbox, machine-learning

I am attempting to calculate and save an image statistics file on a landsat 8 scene. When attempting the virtual raster and separate band files no output is created:

```
2016-04-01T16:26:13 0   OTB execution command
            C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\otbcli_ComputeImagesStatistics
            -il
            "C:\Users\Rion Lerm\Desktop\Bulk Order 628994\L8 OLI_TIRS\2015-07-16\reprojectedToWgs84\PAN_LC81680772015197LGN00_B5.TIF " "C:\Users\Rion Lerm\Desktop\Bulk Order 628994\L8 OLI_TIRS\2015-07-16\reprojectedToWgs84\PAN_LC81680772015197LGN00_B4.TIF " "C:\Users\Rion Lerm\Desktop\Bulk Order 628994\L8 OLI_TIRS\2015-07-16\reprojectedToWgs84\PAN_LC81680772015197LGN00_B3.TIF " "C:\Users\Rion Lerm\Desktop\Bulk Order 628994\L8 OLI_TIRS\2015-07-16\reprojectedToWgs84\PAN_LC81680772015197LGN00_B2.TIF "
            -bv
            0
            -out
            "C:/Users/Rion Lerm/Desktop/olifantsRiver_scp_classifies/otb_trainingClassifier/image_stats_bands2to5"
2016-04-01T16:26:13 0   OTB execution console output
```

...and then no output?

---

Attempted kmeans unsupervised via OTB (orfeo) and the following error appeared (QGIS 2.14). I performed it on a virtual raster composed of various landsat 8 bands:

`2016-04-08T10:23:01    0   OTB execution command
            C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\otbcli_KMeansClassification
            -in
            "C:\Users\Rion Lerm\Desktop\Bulk_Order628994\L8_OLI_TIRS\2015-07-16\reprojectedToWgs84\landsat_projectedToWgs84.vrt"
            -ram
            7000
            -ts
            100
            -nc
            7
            -maxit
            1000
            -ct
            0.0001
            -out
            "C:/Users/Rion Lerm/Desktop/olifantsRiver_scp_classifies/2015_landCover_classify_olifantsRiver_kmeans.tif"
            -outmeans
            "C:\Users\RIONLE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\processing9b135f51bd084ee9a73e3f9100b6ae29\77bd7262ce7948e8bc780c22999c2dcf\outmeans.file"
2016-04-08T10:23:01 0   Adapter for adaptKMeansClassification not found
2016-04-08T10:23:01 0   OTB execution console output
2016-04-08T10:23:01 2   Error loading result layer:
            Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "C:/Users/Rion Lerm/.qgis2/python/plugins\processing\gui\Postprocessing.py", line 76, in handleAlgorithmResults
                out.name))
              File "C:/Users/Rion Lerm/.qgis2/python/plugins\processing\tools\dataobjects.py", line 194, in load
                + '\nCheck the procesing framework log to look for errors')
            RuntimeError: Could not load layer: C:/Users/Rion Lerm/Desktop/olifantsRiver_scp_classifies/2015_landCover_classify_olifantsRiver_kmeans.tif
            Check the procesing framework log to look for errors`

Please assist!

Answer (score 1):

Could you please copy paste the log content ?

I am not sure but I see space in the path of your file.

Generaly it could generateberror message just for that. 
So you can try to move your input file in a folder where the full path don't have space.

Comment: Hi @Cedriclardeux, I added additional log content to the question.